# Convert Custom Cordova Plugin to Windows 8/RT

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, windows-8

I am in the midst of converting a html/javascript app that runs on iOS/Android to work on Windows 8/RT.  I have most of the HTML/Javascript/jQuery working on the Windows 8/RT but need to figure out to get the plugin working on windows 8.

That said I have a couple questions.

1) What is the native language of Windows 8/RT?

- In Android, my Javascript plugin talks to a JAVA file and returns a
  pluginresult.  What is the equivalent on Windows 8?

2) Is there any documentation on how to setup a Windows 8 plugin?

- The Phonegap page only currently lists Windows Phone 8/7
  documentation.

3) The Cordova plugin supports a window.openDatabase function for both iOS and Android, is there an equivalent on Windows 8?

4) Does Windows 8 allow Bluetooth communication?

- related topic here [Windows Store Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360787/windows-store-bluetooth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The core WinRT components are written in C++.  You can write your own components in C++, C#, or VB.NET.  No matter what language the WinRT component is written in, you can access it from JavaScript, C#, VB.NET, or C++.  Windows Store apps can be written in any of those languages.  They're all fully supported by Microsoft.
2. [Creating Windows Runtime Components in C# and Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx).  [Creating Windows Runtime Components in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441569%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
3. window.openDatabase creates a SQLite database.  [You can use your own SQLite database for a Windows Store app](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/).  [There's also a way to use SQLite from JavaScript](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT).  Alternatively, since you're using JavaScript, you can use [the IndexedDB capability in HTML5](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/IndexedDB-sample-eb1e95af/view/SourceCode).
4. Yes, Windows 8 supports Bluetooth.  [Look at Windows.Networking.Proximity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.aspx).

Comment: Matt - on the Windows.Networking.Proximity - that appears to be a class that is only with a close proximity ie within 3-4 centimeters.  Is there a BluetoothSocket class like there is for android?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bluetooth support in Android. Can you tell me more about what you want to do?

Comment: Essentially, you create a Bluetooth Device member variable and populate that member with the device information, which is a native call.  That will give you a list of paired devices, and you just open a Bluetooth socket to that device and then its the standard socket operations on a in/outstream for read/write.

Comment: You can definitely control a Bluetooth device for handling a call (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Call-Control-b52ad696), but I don't know about opening sockets.

Comment: Okay thanks, basically I just need the ability to write/read to a Bluetooth device as if I were communicating to a COM port.  I might have to write a windows component for this.. not sure though.

Comment: I would open a separate question just on your Bluetooth issue, if I were you.